# Are all values in a Primary Key Indexed?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

Following a Tutorial on Cassandra, it was mentioned that if I do the following:

`PRIMARY KEY(id, name)` that id is the partition key and hence it is indexed. The name is the clustering column and hence it is also indexed. This means I can do a query such as:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id = 'id_abc'; //this works!
```

I can also do a query such as:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id = 'id_abc' AND name = 'name_123'; // this works!
```

However, I cannot do the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE name = 'name_123'; // this does not work
```

Why does the last statement not work if the clustering column is indexed? Why does the first query work and not the second?

The error I get for the last query is the following:

```
InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Cannot execute this query as it might involve data filtering and thus may have unpredictable performance. If you want to execute this query despite the performance unpredictability, use ALLOW FILTERING"
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because it is named primary key there is no index on it in cassandra. `ìd` is your partition key - it defines which node in cassandra is responsible for your `id`. The clustering column `name` defines the order inside the partition.

Therefore `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE name = 'name_123'; // this does not work` whould require all partitions to be scanned, which cassandra by default refuses.